# phpmyadmin not showing triggers tab

Tags: phpmyadmin

My Mysql version is:

> Server version: 5.5.55-0+deb7u1-log (Debian)

I log to phpmyadmin as **root with ALL privileges**. I got the "conceptor" tab (to make joins visually between tables), but I don't have the trigger tab.

How to enable the trigger tab ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using phpMyadmin version 4.6.5.2. I find 'triggers' as shown in the picture below . Go to the database and in the upper menu , you will find 'More' menu item. Click on it and the the dropdown will reveal to show 'Triggers'.

[image: Triggers in phpMyAdmin]